# strcpy issue with char pointer in c

Tags: pointers, struct, malloc

I have a problem with strcpy in C. My Code:

**student.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    char *name;      /**< char pointer to name of Student */
    char *grades;    /**< char pointer to grades of labs */
    float mark;      /**< float as mark of labs */
} Student;

Student *new_student(char *, char *);
```

**student.c**

```
include "student.h"
Student *new_student(char *name, char *grades) {

    if (name == NULL || strlen(name) == 0) return NULL;
    char *marks = "";
    //if (grades == NULL) grades = "";
    if(grades == NULL){
        marks= "";
    }
    else{
       marks= grades;
    }

Student *test;
test = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student));

(void)strcpy(&test->name, name);
    (void)strcpy(&test->grades, noten);

return test;
}
```

and my main check.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "student.h"


int main() {

     Student *s;
     s = new_student("Test", "ABC");
     printf("%s",&s->name);

    /*(void)test_student(0, NULL);*/
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The Problem is the printf statement returns TestABC instead of just Test. I just dont get it why. I just want the name not the name and the grades togehter in my printf statement. Can anyone help?

Comment: Look at your `Student` struct and ask yourself where you're storing those  strings. I don't see any arrays, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got several problems here.

First, change your `struct` declaration to allocate space for your character strings. I randomly picked 100 for array sizes; change that to whatever size makes sense.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];  /**< name of Student */
    char grades[100];/**< grades of labs */
    float mark;      /**< float as mark of labs */
} Student;
```

Next, change your `new_student` function as follows:

```
Student *test;
test = malloc(sizeof(Student));

strcpy(test->name, name);
strcpy(test->grades, noten);
```

Finally, fix your `printf` statement in `main` to look like this:

```
printf("%s", s->name);
```

Comment: ty that helped me to fix the problem. I just started to learn C, so im very thankful for any advice :).

Comment: @member2 You're welcome, but the usual way to express appreciation is to upvote and accept the answer.